# WordPress ACF Repeater - the loop through a repeater not returns the sub value fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**What I have**

I have a repeater setup in Advanced custom fields and bootstrap slider in my code.

[the reapter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKkda.png)

1. The repeater is applied to: page=home.
2. The code runs inside: front-page.php
3. the_sub_field('client-name') returns text

Repeater field name = '**client-testimonial**'
Repeater sub fields = '**client-name**'   ,  '**client-role**'

**What I trying to achieve**

display the values in an html webpage. *the loop does not return the sub-fileds values*

```
   <div class="reapter">
        <h1>reapeter</h1>
        <?php if( have_rows('client-testimonial') ): ?> 
             <ul>    
                <?php while ( have_rows('client-testimonial') ) : the_row(); ?>
                        <li><p><?php the_sub_field('client-name'); ?></p></li> 
                        <li><p><?php the_sub_field('client-role'); ?></p></li> 
                <?php endwhile; ?>
           </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is this code located? On a post template? Is the `the_post` function called before executing it? What does `get_field('client-testimonial')` return?

Comment: Please update your post with the ACF code.

Comment: if your outside the loop, then you need to specify the post id, to read the rows - Are you getting the `ul` html?